# Decoding deeply nested object in Swift using nested structs

Tags: ios, swift

my goal is to decode a deeply nested json response from an api and render it in a list, below is the raw response data and my attempt.

The problem is that when I attempt to initialize my data to then further populated when I make my API call it gives me an error

“ Listing(data: []) { *ERROR: No exact matches in call to initializer*”

Is this the correct way to declare my structs to decode a deeply nested JSON Object?

Api response data ->
https://pastebin.com/7pgswZqk

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine


struct Listing: Decodable {
    var kind: String
    struct data: Decodable {
        var modhash: String
        var dist: Int
        struct children: Decodable {
            var kind: String
            struct data: Decodable {    <--- this level is where my iterable children are
                var title: String
                ... <---- there is more properties here but I just put title for now
            }
        }
    }
}

class NetworkingManager : ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkingManager, Never>()
    
    var ListingList = Listing(data: []) { *ERROR: No exact matches in call to initializer*
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/best.json?limit=25") else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            let List = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Listing.self, from: data)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.ListingList = List
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Then to iterate over the list, would it be like this?

```
List(ListingList.data.children.data.identified(by ./title) {listItem in
    Text(listItem.title)
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking

Comment: Added more context, thanks

Comment: `var ListingList = Listing(data: [])`, this is not how you declare a variable. Try `var listingList: Listing` (variable should start with lowercase letters).

Comment: Seems like you're missing the declaration of the actual var for your custom Decodable types. your `struct Children` is defined but no where used. Also class/struct names should start with an uppercase letter to not get confused with instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your custom Decodable nested structs but missing their application.

Your Listing should look something like this...

```
struct Listing: Decodable {
    var kind: String
    var data: Data // instance of custom Listing.Data struct
    struct Data: Decodable { // your custom decodable struct
        var modhash: String
        var dist: Int
        var children: [Children] // instance of your custom Listing.Data.Children struct
        struct Children: Decodable { // your custom decodable struct
            var kind: String
            var data: Data
            struct Data: Decodable {
                var title: String
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...but it becomes unreadable very quickly so better create separate structs instead of nesting. In the following example you can see that naming can become kindof tedious when having deeply nested responses.

```
struct Listing: Decodable {
    var kind: String
    var data: ListingData
}

struct ListingData: Decodable {
    var modhash: String
    var dist: Int
    var children: [ListingDataChildren]
}

struct ListingDataChildren: Decodable {
    var kind: String
    var data: ListingDataChildrenData
}

struct ListingDataChildrenData: Decodable {
    var title: String
    // ...
}
```

The optimal solution would be to create extensions to still have that kind of hierarchy that you get via nesting.

```
struct Listing: Decodable {
    var kind: String
    var data: Data
}

extension Listing {
    struct Data: Decodable {
        var modhash: String
        var dist: Int
        var children: [Children]
    }
}

extension Listing.Data {
    struct Children: Decodable {
        var kind: String
        var data: Data
    }
}

extension Listing.Data.Children {
    struct Data: Decodable {
        var title: String
        // ...
    }
}
```